# printing array with a loop (for) and a condition

Tags: java, arrays, printing

Well I need to print the months with lower numbers than the average (the average it's already there) but I'm having trouble trying to print just the months, it prints the right months but it cycles and prints several times in the same month, how can I correct this?
If you need extra info pls comment, I don't really know what else to write in here because I think it's a minor issue

```
package Empresa;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        Company ob1= new Company();
         int prodTable[][] = new int[12][1];
         int totalProd[] = new int[12];
         
        String[] months={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July","August", "September"
                ,"October", "November","December"};
        
        String monthsPrint="";
        
        System.out.println("Fill the information required: \n");
        ob1.capture();
        System.out.println("Enter the company's mission: ");
        ob1.setMission(input.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the company's vision: ");
        ob1.setVision(input.next());
        System.out.println("Number of employees: ");
        ob1.setEmployees(input.nextInt());
        ob1.show();
        comProd(months,monthsPrint,prodTable,totalProd);
        rowsAdd(months,monthsPrint,prodTable,totalProd);
        
    }
    
    public static void comProd( String months[],String monthsPrint, int prodTable[][],int totalProd[] ){ 
        System.out.println("\t\t\nProduction statistics\n");
        System.out.println("Months\t\tNumber");

        for (int k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
            monthsPrint = (months[k] + "                        ").substring(0, 15);
            int number = 0;
            System.out.print(monthsPrint + "\t");
            
            for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++) {
                prodTable[k][m] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
                System.out.print(prodTable[k][m] + "\t");
                number = number + prodTable[k][m];                     
            }                  
           System.out.println();
            totalProd[k] = number;
        }
      }
    
    public static void rowsAdd(String months[], String monthsPrint, int prodTable[][],int totalProd[]){ 
        int higher = 0;
        int higherMonth = 0; 
        String lowMonths ="";
        int lMonth = 0;
        double average=0;
        double totalaverage=0;
                for (int k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
                    average = average + totalProd[k];
                    int number = 0;
                    for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++) { 
                        number = number + prodTable[k][m];
                         
                    }
                    if (totalProd[k] > higher) {
                        higher = totalProd[k];
                        higherMonth = k;
                        
                    } 
                   
                    totalaverage=average/12;             
                    for (int j=0;j <12;j++) {
                        if (totalProd[j] <totalaverage) {
                            lowMonths = months[j];
                            lMonth = j;
                            System.out.println("The months with lower production than the average are " + months[j]);
                        } 
                        
                    } 
                }
              
                System.out.format("\nAverage production of the year:%.3f",totalaverage);
                
                System.out.println("\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------------");  
              
                System.out.println("The month with the highest production was " + months[higherMonth]);
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Process Finished\n\n");
  }
   


}
```

Comment: What do you suppose the two loops like this do?  `for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++)`  How many times will it loop?

Comment: I suppose just one time? @passer-by